# An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Proj.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When i put a break point on Index method and after executing the line `_model.SubCategoryList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select Any ", Value = "0" });`, I'm getting below error.

> > An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Proj.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
> >
> > Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        _model = new FA_AssetCreationModel { };            
        _model.SubCategoryList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select Any ", Value = "0" });           
        return View("Creation", _model);
    }
```

I need to set a default value for the dropdownlist on page load inorder to avoid another error `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items`.

Comment: Because `SubCategoryList` is `null` - you have not initialized it

Comment: Can you help me to initialize `Text = "Select Any ", Value = "0"` to the list `public List<SelectListItem> SubCategoryList { get; set; }`

Comment: `_model = new FA_AssetCreationModel { SubCategoryList = new List<SelectListItem>() };` - now its not `null` so you can add items to it

Comment: Alternatively, initialize it in the default constructor for `FA_AssetCreationModel` -  `public FA_AssetCreationModel() {  SubCategoryList = new List<SelectListItem>(); }`